# IEPE Circuit Model

Tags: circuit-analysis, datalogger

Do anybody have a circuit model of a IEPE Loop?

I am requiring to model the response of IEPE loops for checking how the frequency response of a sensor can or cannot be degraded under changes on the design i am currently having - cable, DAQ, etc.

Some details here, without parameters enabling me to model anything.
https://www.pcb.com/Resources/Technical-information/tech_signal#collapse13

The loop components are:

- A data acquisition module DAQ,
- An IEPE sensor,
- A cable between them.

The main parameters are the following:

- DAQ Excitation Current $I$,
- DAQ Excitation Voltage $V$,
- DAQ Impedances. Here i am also not clear on which the current & voltage vary under changes on the IEPE variable gain,
- Cable per length parameters: impedance, capacitance, inductance, resistance,
- Sensor variable "gain/impedance". In here i am not clear on which parameters i should consider over the IEPE (pre)amplifier embedded with the sensor.

For more details, if they are eventually required, just check this previous post:
[PCB 393B04 IEPE Accelerometer + NI 9230 DAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267319/pcb-393b04-iepe-accelerometer-ni-9230-daq)

Thanks in advance.
[image: IEPE Block Diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IEPE stands for Integrated Electronics Piezo Electric

- it defines a class of accelerometer that has built in electronics.

  - usually low impedance output electronics that work on a two wire
    constant current supply with an voltage output on a DC voltage bias.
  - The IEPE technology has generally replaced most 3 wire accelerometers and is broadly used for most applications except DC stable, high temp, 4-20mA in SCADA
  - There are many different type of accelerometers

**This is what you need**
[image]

Comment: Dear Tony, I appreciate your answer. I already have this reference, and pasted it in the question. I am looking on how to model the amplifier... I want to know how some parameters affect, such as the cable impedance or serial resistors. :o

Comment: It is not affected by cable impedance or series R since it has relatively low source Z with the load being current source into a bias R front end and is AC coupled out. and for  the same reason ,  sensors with 4-20ma are not affected. SHielded or twisted pair cable is needed  tho and perhaps a large CM choke however if near large dI/dt H fields